# No bean found for class despite @Component and @Bean

Tags: spring, grizzly

I have this class that creates a socket on the java side.  The problem is that it's throwing a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No bean found for class com.production.workflow.process.approval.ApprovalSocketHandler`

```
package com.production;

@WebListener
public class SocketInitializer implements ServletContextListener {

    public static App app;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        app =  new App(new Options().url("/socket/workstation/approval").packageOf(this), new AtmosphereModule(servletContextEvent.getServletContext()), new SpringModule(beanFactory));
        app.bean(ApprovalSocketHandler.class).init();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    }
}
```

The package that this class is in, is indeed being scanned via my config.  I suspect that at the point this Listener is being initialized that config hasn't yet scanned.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.production"
})
@PropertySource(value= {
        "classpath:/application.properties",
        "classpath:/environment-${MY_ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.production.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
    @Value("${db.url}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_URL;
    @Value("${db.user}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_USER;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${persistenceUnit.default}")
    String PROPERTY_DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_DIALECT;
    @Value("${hibernate.format_sql}")
    String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL;
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;
    @Value("${entitymanager.packages.to.scan}")
    String PROPERTY_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Bean
    public App app() {
        return SocketInitializer.app;
    }
```

What do I need to do in order to ensure this class is a bean during ServletContextListener execution?

Comment: `ServletContextListener`s are loaded and registered by the servlet container.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - What's the significance of that in this scenario?

Comment: Servlet container processes things before Spring does, so the beans won't be available at `contextInitialized`. I don't have a solution for you though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Well... if you happen to know how I can inject `ServletContext` into my configuration class then you'll have solved my issue in another way.

Comment: Check out the `ServletContextAware` interface.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! I've added details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface [`ServletContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/) is what you are looking for. It provides the method

```
setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext)
```

which Spring will use to inject the application context. In your case, this will be the `ServletContext` created by your servlet container.

You should not be using this with `ServletContextListener` as you have it in your question since a `ServletContextListener` is initialized by the servlet container and not by Spring. Spring cannot therefore do its magic.